# Why does limit: $\lim_{x\to\infty}\prod\limits^{\lfloor x\rfloor}_{n=1}\frac{\lceil x\rceil}{\lfloor x\rfloor}=e$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions, infinite-product

This is for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $x\notin\mathbb{Z}$ because it equals $1$ for all positive integers.

I was just messing around with floor and ceiling functions in Desmos when I came upon this. I have not been able to prove this and it is at the moment only an observation.
To me, this makes absolutely no sense and I have no clue how to begin solving this. When typing it into WolframAlpha, it just gave me an answer of $1$ because it did not exclude integers. It also gave me a partial product formula of $\left(\frac{\lceil x\rceil}{\lfloor x\rfloor}\right)^n$ but this seems like it would not work for $n=\infty$. This is what it looks like in Desmos:
[image]
Is anyone able to explain this to me? How do you even prove this? Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: @aschepler The OP's title doesn't match their question

Comment: OP's attached picture clearly says what the author means, just the title is not well written. @MartinR

Comment: Thanks for fixing the question. I am not quite sure why mine was incorrect, but I appreciate it nonetheless.

Comment: It's clear to me what OP means and what MathFail said. OP just has confused their Desmos graph with their title

Comment: @FShrike Thanks. Would you mind explaining what was different between the original question and what I meant. I thought because I used the same equation that I used in the Desmos, it would be the same. Sorry if this doesn't make sense, I am just quite confused.

Comment: @DylanLevine $\prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{\lceil x\rceil}$ is very different to $\lim_{x\to\infty}\prod_{n=1}^{\lfloor x\rfloor}\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{\lceil x\rceil}$

Comment: Oh I see where I went wrong. Thanks for clarifying that for me

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let $k=\lfloor x\rfloor$

$$\prod\limits^{\lfloor x\rfloor}_{n=1}\frac{\lceil x\rceil}{\lfloor x\rfloor}=\prod\limits^{k}_{n=1}\frac{k+1}{k}=\left( 1+\frac1k\right)^k$$

therefore,

$$\lim_{x\to\infty\land x\notin\mathbb N}\prod\limits^{\lfloor x\rfloor}_{n=1}\frac{\lceil x\rceil}{\lfloor x\rfloor}=\lim_{k\to\infty}\left( 1+\frac1k\right)^k=e$$

Comment: What is $n$? This makes as little sense to me as the OP did.

Comment: @TedShifrin the multiplicand just doesn't depend on $n$ so we get a product of constants

Comment: Note OP is not dependent on $n$, that's why it gets $e$

Comment: What you’ve written makes absolutely no sense. $x$ is fixed, so how did its integer part turn into a variable integer $k$?

Comment: You read the attached picture in OP, x is not fixed @TedShifrin

Comment: It’s the same number multiplied n times, aka the n-th power. And we can call the integer part of x anything we like, for example k.

Comment: Note that when $x$ is an integer, this evaluates to $1$, not $e$, so the limit isn’t actually defined.

Comment: Read the first sentence of OP, the author said that. @Eric

Comment: Read the first sentence of OP, the author said that. @dxiv

Comment: Sure, but limit notation doesn’t work like that. It’s better to explicitly either state you are using a weird version of limit that skips points we know are bad or put it into your notation explicitly, maybe as $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}_{x\not \in \mathbb{Z}}$

Comment: This would be like saying that noting that $1/0$ isn’t defined and then stating that $\sum_{n=-5}^5 1/n=0$. This isn’t true and you have to explicitly state you are jumping bad points.

Comment: OK, it is added! @Eric

Comment: OK, it is added! @dxiv